# Benchmarking Rails Model Methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, benchmarking

Is there something similar to Ruby Benchmark within Rails? I have used Ruby benchmark in the past to compare different bits of code, but none of it was Rails related. I would like to use my application models in some benchmarking to do something along the lines of...

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report("Benchmark 1") do 
    1_000_000.times do
      # do something here...
    end
  end

  x.report("Benchmark 2") do
    1_000_000.times do
      # Do something else here...
    end
  end
end
```

Which gives me some output like this:

```
Rehearsal -----------------------------------------------
Benchmark 1   0.070000   0.000000   0.070000 (  0.069236)
Benchmark 2   0.070000   0.000000   0.070000 (  0.069227)
-------------------------------------- total: 0.140000sec

                  user     system      total        real
Benchmark 1   0.070000   0.000000   0.070000 (  0.069793)
Benchmark 2   0.070000   0.000000   0.070000 (  0.069203)
```

I looked into script/performance/benchmarker and script/performance/profiler, but I couldn't figure out a way to compare methods. I also looked into doing it within a test, but I don't have any sort of assertions, so that didn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Performance testing your rails application](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.0.0/performance_testing.html) might be all you need. I think that's all you can do with standalone Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Rails added a benchmark generator.

```
rails g benchmark some_benchmark
```

it creates the file at

```
script/benchmarks/some_benchmark.rb
```

It should automatically add the ips-benchmark gem to your gemfile after running bundle but if it doesn't just add it under the development section in your gemfile.

run it in the terminal by doing

```
ruby script/benchmarks/some_benchmark.rb
```

since it loads config/environment.rb in the benchmark file all models are accessible.